# Is there any solution to prevent extra line in pop up alert in the react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

As shown in the attached picture, I would like to update my code. When I click the button/submit button second time, the dialog box creates default message like this: **Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs**

Is there any solution which prevents this default message?

Comment: No, There isn't.

Comment: @pythonbuddha that is the default message added by the browser, that can't be removed, since it protects the user from getting unnecessary alerts created by some malicious websites